# PHP Warning when attempting to use stat() or filemtime()

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface

I am attempting to get the last modified time of a file that definately does exist:
/document_root/myfile.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x    1 11018    11008      198621 Nov 26  2007 myfile.pdf

When i run the following statement (through PHP CLI as root):
filemtime('/document_root/myfile.pdf');

I get errors:
Warning: stat(): Stat failed for /document_root/myfile.pdf
 (errno=2 - No such file or directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the **file path wrong** or you **don't have permission** to stat the relevant file.

Wrong file path?

```
filemtime('/document_root/myfile.pdf');
```

Right file path?

```
filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/myfile.pdf');
```

Check the file's permissions: can the file be read by the user under which PHP is running?

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing something like running this from within a function where you haven't passed through a value for document_root?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've got the right path?

/document_root/myfile.pdf

Looks like an absolute path, but I doubt your "document_root" is in the root filesystem.

If that's not it, also make sure that the apache user has read access to the file itself, but also r+x access to all directories leading up to the file path.